# Text Join in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following Problem:

I try to join a Text together in one Column:

Basically I want to join something like "Text 1" + "Number extract 1 of ColumnX" + "Text 2" + "Number extract 2 of a columnX"

This does not work:

```
df["EINGRUPPIERUNG"]="P",df["PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG]"].str.findall(r"\d+")[:][0]," ","Stufe ",df["PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG]"].str.findall(r"\d+")[:][1]
```

This are my number extracts and the other text is basically hardcoded.

```
df["PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG]"].str.findall(r"\d+")
0        [8, 4]
1        [8, 5]
2        [8, 5]
3        [8, 4]
4        [7, 4]
          ...  
13441    [9, 3]
13442    [9, 3]
13443    [9, 3]
13444    [9, 3]
13445    [8, 4]
Name: PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG], Length: 13446, dtype: object
```

thanks for your help
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str` accessor to get individual element of a list:

```
match = df['PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG]'].str.findall(r'\d+')
df['EINGRUPPIERUNG'] = 'P' + match.str[0] + ' Stufe ' + match.str[1]
print(out)

# Output
  PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG] EINGRUPPIERUNG
0        blah 8 blah 4     P8 Stufe 4
1        blah 8 blah 5     P8 Stufe 5
2        blah 8 blah 5     P8 Stufe 5
```

Or with `str.extract`:

```
match = df['PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG]'].str.extract(r'(\d+).*(\d+)', expand=True)
df['EINGRUPPIERUNG'] = 'P' + match[0] + ' Stufe ' + match[1]
```

You can also use `replace`:

```
>>> df['PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG]'].replace(r'.*(\d+).*(\d+).*',
                                       r'P\1 Stufe \2', regex=True)
0    P8 Stufe 4
1    P8 Stufe 5
2    P8 Stufe 5
Name: PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG], dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the example df in Corralien's example, here is another way using `str.findall()` and `map()` with `format()`:

```
df['PROJEKT[BEZEICHNUNG]'].str.findall(r'\d+').map('P {0[0]} Stufe {0[1]}'.format)
```

Output:

```
0    P 8 Stufe 4
1    P 8 Stufe 5
2    P 8 Stufe 5
```